# Error while creating/importing skill in watson assistant with lite plan

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-conversation

While trying out the [banking chatbot](https://github.com/IBM/watson-banking-chatbot) demo I am unable to import a skill with the json file mentioned for the demo. It is a valid json file but import fails with an error

"We could not import your Skill. Unable to fetch access token for account: "

I have a lite plan. I am uploading the json file from the IBM cloud UI using the "Launch tool" option in watson assistant.

I could not find a solution/workaround to this.

Comment: How did you deploy? Are you logged in? Please provide more details.

Comment: Yes, I am logged in to the ibm cloud and importing the json through the "Launch tool" option

Comment: That looks like an (intermittent?) authorization issue to me. Retry. BTW: I just imported that banking.json into my own Lite plan and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to reload the tool page in the browser. I sometimes see an issue when I have left browser windows open for some time and the authorization token for the web app expired. Reloading that window would check and the bring up the login page. Also trying to open the browser in incognito mode could also help.

The banking workspace ([banking.json](https://github.com/IBM/watson-banking-chatbot/blob/master/data/conversation/workspaces/banking.json)) works in my lite plan of IBM Watson Assistant.

Comment: I have tried reloading the tools page multiple times but I keep getting the same error. Note that the error comes also when I click on the "Launch tool page". The wordings are a bit different "Integrations could not be loaded at this time. Unable to fetch access token for account: <account-id>"

Comment: Then start off at cloud.ibm.com, go to your services and launch it from there.

Comment: You might also try different browser and different computer - to rule out computer/browser-based issue...

Comment: Amazing. Trying it with incognito mode on the browser did the trick and the skills got important. Thanks for the help.